# using awk to print line number with output lines

Tags: awk

context: [grep for multiple strings in file on different lines (ie. whole file, not line based search)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795323/grep-for-multiple-strings-in-file-on-different-lines-ie-whole-file-not-line-b)

```
egrep -nH 'Dansk|Norsk|Svenska' file3
```

or using [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

```
rg  'Dansk|Norsk|Svenska' file3
```

But there is an answer

```
awk '/Dansk/{a=1}/Norsk/{b=1}/Svenska/{c=1}END{ if (a && b && c) print $0 }'  file3
```

I don't understand [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4795531/15603477) answer.

I understand `awk '/Dansk/{a=1}/Norsk/{b=1}/Svenska/{c=1}` .

I think now the question is using awk, while pattern matched, print line number with output lines.

update:
I even understand [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22497489/15603477) answer.
update:
almost close:

```
awk '/Dansk/{a=1}/Norsk/{b=1}/Svenska/{c=1}{ if (a || b || c ) print $0; next}1'  file3
```

it return

```
Subtitle: 04, Language: da - Dansk, Content: Undefined, Stream id: 0x23,
        Subtitle: 05, Language: de - Deutsch, Content: Undefined, Stream id: 0x24,
```

the expected return is

```
   Subtitle: 04, Language: da - Dansk, Content: Undefined, Stream id: 0x23,
```

`file3` content:

```
Disc Title: unknown
Title: 01, Length: 01:33:37.000 Chapters: 33, Cells: 31, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 20
        Subtitle: 01, Language: ar - Arabic, Content: Undefined, Stream id: 0x20, 
        Subtitle: 02, Language: bg - Bulgarian, Content: Undefined, Stream id: 0x21, 
        Subtitle: 03, Language: cs - Czech, Content: Undefined, Stream id: 0x22, 
        Subtitle: 04, Language: da - Dansk, Content: Undefined, Stream id: 0x23, 
        Subtitle: 05, Language: de - Deutsch, Content: Undefined, Stream id: 0x24, 
(...)
```

update. almost close.
`awk '/Dansk/{a=1}/Norsk/{b=1}/Svenska/{c=1}{ if (a || b || c ) print NR, $0}'  file3`
But it returns

```
6         Subtitle: 04, Language: da - Dansk, Content: Undefined, Stream id: 0x23,
7         Subtitle: 05, Language: de - Deutsch, Content: Undefined, Stream id: 0x24,
8 (...)
```

Comment: other answer has explanation, which part you don't understand? or you understood as you have written _understand_. also please don't point to a code by just giving the link to it, but also mention exact code in your question.

Comment: @αғsнιη I am almost close. I get the matched line and the next line. I don't want next line.  see my updates.

Comment: `x||y||z||...` means "if x OR y OR z OR ... were _True_" then do something. `x&&y&&z&&...` means "if x AND y AND z AND ... _all_ were _True_" then do something."True" means a result of an expression or condition evaluated _true_. I believe you strongly need to start first reading some basics of awk commnad.

Comment: @αғsнιη to clarify my question. to emulate `rg  'Dansk|Norsk|Svenska' file3` command which return ` Subtitle: 04, Language: da - Dansk, Content: Undefined, Stream id: 0x23,` but now my `awk` idea return the matched line and the next line. I only want matched line. now I don't know how to improve it.

Comment: you changed your command and now you are expecting to see the same result as rg returns?! no, you are going in wrong way. In one of your previous question I answered what does `1` means in awk, but sounds you didn't learn it. you need improve your reading

Comment: about `awk '/Dansk/{a=1}/Norsk/{b=1}/Svenska/{c=1}{ if (a || b || c ) print NR, $0}'` you can just do `awk '/Dansk|Norsk|Svenska/{print NR, $0}'`, but I really don't know what are you trying to do here at all. what is your question and goal now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk is consist of pair of condition(s) & action(s) which condition part can be any arithmetic expression or pattern matching or result of one-or-more expression which all of these result can be true or false statement;

and here, the given sample is used a pair of pattern matching and actions which is:

```
awk '/if-this-regex-exist-in-current-line/ { "yes, so do something" }' infile
```

all of 3 doing the same pattern matching and set a temporary variable flag if those regex found in a line.

then at the END{} block, which this block only runs once after all records/line of the input infile file processed, which it simply checking if those all flags were set (means all 3 patterns were found either those were found in a single line or in while input file), then print the *last line* (you might wanted to print FILENAME instead or something else) of the input file.

---

Answer to the second added question about:

```
awk '/Dansk/{a=1}/Norsk/{b=1}/Svenska/{c=1}{ if (a || b || c ) print $0; next}1' file3
```

this prints the lines where that line was contain at least one of `Dansk` or `Norsk` or `Svenska` in it, otherwise print the line which all what this commnad do can be written `awk 1 infile` or `cat infile`.

In `x ||y ||z || ...` means "if x OR y OR z OR ... at least one were True" then do something while in `x && y && z &&...` means "if x AND y AND z AND ... all of them were True" then do something; "True" means a result of an expression(s) or a condition(s) evaluated true result.